# Possible to run Google Standard Managed VM Locally with Docker for Development?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, docker, managed-vm, google-managed-vm

Is it possible to run a Google Standard Managed VM for Java locally for development purposes? I am asking cause dev_appserver.py, mvn gcloud:run or gcloud preview app run are good for a simple hello world application, but anything bigger than that doesn't work... (single threaded, timeout, etc...).

Comment: I have not used Java, but the standard python managed VM works on the dev server. They do it without even using docker...

Comment: You may want to check out appstart: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appstart

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this above, but you're looking for AppStart:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appstart